# Confused by Typesafe Activator Offline Distribution

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I downloaded typesafe activator offline distribution and configure path. However I cannot create project while offline, cannot generate IDEA project while offline, cannot even do a run while offline. I am missing something or what does the offline distribution suppose to mean? Also just the past few days there's been versions 1.2.3 then 1.2.6 and then 1.2.7. Where can we find the release notes, so that we know what has changed? I think the initial play distribution was newbie friendly but activator even though claimed to get one started easily, I tend to believe the opposite. I find it hard to get up and running as compared the initial play distribution.